# What documents do I need to carry if I am applying for a business visit visa for the UK to attend a 2 days long client conference?

Tags: business-travel

I have an invitation letter from the client based in the UK. I have a NOC from my employer stating my passport number, annual remuneration, job description, duration of visit and assurance of taking care of my expenses.

I own a house that I bought 4 months back, I have a wife and 4-month-old baby (they are not traveling with me) as dependents.

I have company's bank statements, taxation details, pan card details, my salary slips, my bank statements etc.

Am I missing anything? Do I need to carry a translated copy of my birth certificate? Do I need to carry my son's birth certificate as well?

Any other documents that I might be missing? I am seeking a 2-year multiple entries visa because I might need to make more trips in the future. Also, the conference is in just 3 weeks so I have chosen the express option that delivers in 5 working days.

Comment: You don't need your birth certificate and your child's birth certificate on your application. Your existing documentation seems to be fine. Just follow the checklist that will be given to you and provide all the information requested there

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, you are going to need your passport, which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: thanks for reminding DJClayworth, don't want to forget that.